# What is the difference between qbinom and pbinom in R?

Tags: r, binomial-distribution

The documentation of binomial functions everywhere is very unclear. Can someone please answer with examples?

Comment: Can you explain what is unclear in the documentation? You shouldn't blame documentation if you lack background knowledge.

Comment: If you don't like R documentation this is not the place to complain!

Answer (score 2):

**From the doc:**

`dbinom` gives the density, `pbinom` gives the distribution function, `qbinom` gives the quantile function and `rbinom` generates random deviates.

The quantile is defined as the smallest value x such that F(x) ≥ p, where F is the distribution function.

---

There exist similar functions for other distributions. E.g., `dnorm`, `pnorm`, `qnorm`, `rnorm`; or `dbeta`, `pbeta`, `qbeta`, `rbeta`.

---

$X \sim \text{Binom}(n, p)$

`pbinom(q = x, size = n, prob = p)` returns $\Pr(X \leq x)$.

`qbinom(p = x, size = n, prob = p)`, with $x \in [0, 1]$, returns the smallest value of $q$ such that $\Pr(X \leq q) \geq x$.